# Ajax not working on PHP page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to understand the basics of using AJAX in conjunction with PHP in order to use php pages to provide functions, but not change my 'view' on my MVC design.

So I created this basic login page...

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <title>learning Php</title>


<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(#"login").click(function() {

        var action = $("#form1").attr("action");
        var form_data = {
            username: $("#username").val(),
            password: $("#password").val(),
            is_ajax: 1
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: action,
            data: form_data,
            success: function(response)
            {   
                if(response == 'success')
                {
                    $("#form1").slideUp('slow', function() {
                        $("#message").html('<p class="success">You have logged in.</p>');
                    };
                }
                else 
                    $("#message").html('<p class="error">Incorrect password or username.</p>');
            }

        });

        return false;
    });

});
</script> 

</head>
<body>
<div>
    <form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="loginForm.php">
        <p>
            <label for="username"> Username: </label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="password"> Password: </label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" /> 
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" id="login" name="login" value="login" /> 
        </p>
    </form>
    <div id="message"></div>
<div>
</body> 
</html>
```

And this was my php page to "handle" to login...

```
<?php

   $is_ajax = $_REQUEST['is_ajax'];
   if(isset($is_ajax) && $is_ajax)
   {
       $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
       $password = $_REQUEST['password'];

       if($username == 'demo' && $password == 'demo')
       {
           echo 'success';
       }
   }
?>
```

The problem I am having is that whenever I submit my login, I am redirected to "/loginForm.php" instead of staying on my current page and having the message change underneath the login form.

I tried using Firebug to help me track down what I suspected to be a javascript error, but to no avail.

Any idea on why I am being redirected or why the form is not submitting via Ajax?

Comment: Does it work any better if you bind `$("#form1").submit()` instead of `$("#login").click()`?

Comment: Side note: use [firebug addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) to debug your code. It will be helpful for you in near future.

Comment: You really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). A [complete login description, with PHP, MySQL and AJAX](http://jayblanchard.net/putting_it_all_together.html) is described in this post.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Understood, this was more or less me just trying to understand how to throw data around using AJAX. Never intended to ever see the light of day outside a lab :)

Comment: well @Christopher take everyone's answers including my own, and you'll have yourself a working demo ;-) cheers

Comment: @Christopher you accepted then unaccepted my answer, no idea. I did make an additional note about your use of an input, which should have been a button and my answer was updated earlier.

Comment: @Fred-ii- See my comment on your answer... I had assumed the mislabled password field was the problem. However, the problem still persists that is refuses to return 'success'

Comment: @Christopher comments are piling up lol - I suggest you try this on another server (some free hosted with PHP support). If you have another that is. Maybe something on your school's server is blocking access to something or there's something on the school's mainframe's cache.

Comment: I agree. I cannot imagine what is going wrong here. It is returning success, but it thinks it is returning something else? Like I said, if I change it to `if(response != 'success')` when I enter everything in, it will come up as "you have logged in"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the typo and Rocky's good catch on the `});  <--- You Missed ")" here`

Both your username and password fields are the same.

```
<label for="username"> Username: </label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
```

and

```
<label for="password"> Password: </label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
```

the 2nd one should read as

```
<input type="text" id="password" name="password" />
```

In using everyone's answer, you will have yourself a working script.

- Remember to hash your password once you go LIVE.

Edit sidenote: I've made a note below about using a button, rather than an input.

---

Here's a rewrite, just in case. However that input needs to be a `<button>`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <title>learning Php</title>


<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#login").click(function() {

        var action = $("#form1").attr("action");
        var form_data = {
            username: $("#username").val(),
            password: $("#password").val(),
            is_ajax: 1
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: action,
            data: form_data,
            success: function(response)
            {   
                if(response == 'success')
                {
                    $("#form1").slideUp('slow', function() {
                        $("#message").html('<p class="success">You have logged in.</p>');
                    });
                }
                else 
                    $("#message").html('<p class="error">Incorrect password or username.</p>');
            }

        });

        return false;
    });

});
</script> 

</head>
<body>
<div>
    <form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="loginForm.php">
        <p>
            <label for="username"> Username: </label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="password"> Password: </label>
            <input type="text" id="password" name="password" /> 



<!--
Your original input
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" /> 
-->
        </p>


<button type="submit" id="login" name="login" />LOGIN</button>

<!--
Your original submit input. Don't use it
        <p>
            <input type="submit" id="login" name="login" value="login" /> 
        </p>
-->

    </form>
    <div id="message"></div>
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

- Your last div just before `</body>` was unclosed `</div>`, I've changed that above.

---

Additional edit from comments.

It seems that there was probably a space inserted somewhere and the use of `trim()` was the final nail to the solution.

`response.trim();`

A special thanks goes out to Jay Blanchard to have given us a helping hand in all this, *cheers Sam!*

References (TRIM):

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: Let's call this one a *group effort* ;-)

Comment: Hmm, for some reason it is STILL failing to login. Even to make sure, I copied your entire re-write and it stilled returned 'incorrect password or username'.

Comment: @Christopher worked fine for me. Did you see my note about the button/input?

Comment: @Christopher I just noticed something else. Your last `<div>` just above `</body>` should be `</div>`. Might have something to do with it.

Comment: Yes, I used the button and got rid of the input... Trying to go through it again and figure out what I am missing... if I get it to work I will re-accept as answer

Comment: I copied over your code again with the changes, and still getting the same message... very strange. I see that in dev tools it is querying the loginForm.php page and returning 200(okay). But I can't tell exactly what is  happening on that php page...

Comment: @Christopher you did see my note about the `<div>` before `</body>` which should read as `</div>`. What browser and version are you using? Did you also refresh your browser, cleared the cache, server cache etc. this has got to work. I've tested this with the latest version of Firefox.

Comment: Yes, I fixed the issue with that </div>. Trying it right now on chrome Version 46.0.2490.86. I will open it with my other browsers and see if the same happens...

Comment: So I opened the console in Firebug, and the return Echo is 'success'.... but the label is wrong.. confusing but at least I know it isn't a ajax problem

Comment: @Christopher I tested on my other machine (on a hosted site) with Chrome, success. How are you accessing this file, on your own machine? Hosted site? If own machine, how? as `http://localhost/file.xxx` or as `file:///file.xxx`? I can't see this failing other than that. Try and add a character set `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` but doubt that will help. Firefox threw me a notice about not having one. I honestly don't know what else to say here, *baffled*. Make sure that JS is indeed loaded with no JS adblock rules.

Comment: Yes, very confusing... I am hosting this off of my school web-server. So files are organized as ` cs.school/~me/phptest/xxx ` Like I said, the response from the loginForm.php is 'success' as shown in my Firebug session..

Comment: @Christopher and make sure your PHP isn't failing you neither, check that. Plus, if on *NIX, `loginForm.php` is not the same as `loginform.php`. check for errors on the PHP side. I'm out of ideas here.

Comment: You should be able to see what the PHP is returning in the browser's console.

Comment: Yes, @JayBlanchard it is returning `success`. and I can see I am sending `username=demo&password=demo&is_ajax=1` . However the label still sets to "incorrect username or password".

Comment: And if I set the `if(response == 'success')` function to `if(response != 'success')` then it displays "you have successfully logged in" like it should...

Comment: Even when I just print out the response it says "success". Perhaps it doesn't like the '==' operator when comparing strings?

Comment: No, `==` is right for comparison. Trim the `response`, there may be a character that you cannot see in the return, like a newline @Christopher

Comment: @Christopher I'm baffled. Like I said earlier, I don't know how you're accessing that, as `http://localhost/file.xxx` or as `file:///file.xxx` in your browser, there is a difference here and if that school's server does let you access to JS/PHP etc. Try it on a free host service, pretty sure you'll see it working. You can try changing `if(isset($is_ajax) && $is_ajax)` to `if(isset($is_ajax))` or `if(!empty($is_ajax))` but kind of doubt it. Both methods for me worked and valid syntax. I don't know what else to say/do here, sorry Christopher.

Comment: @JayBlanchard You son of a ***** :) trim() did the trick. No idea why. Not one clue. But it works now.

Comment: @Christopher Holy *!@*$& lol - you know what? That thought did go through my mind earlier about that `trim()`. *Gawd... why didn't I follow my instinct on that one?*

Comment: That is supposed to be *"you magnificent son of a *****"* ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ It works because there is an invisible character of some sort being sent with the PHP response. Not sure how those get injected, but they do. I *always* trim AJAX responses.

Comment: @Christopher you might of had a space in your input somewhere. When entering a space at the end of either inputs, did in fact throw me an error of "Incorrect password or username". Funny what a space will do to someone's day. Oh well, problem solved and Jay's comment helped us all through all of this. Glad to see this one was solved, all the best my friend, *cheers*

Answer (score 3):

One more mistake here

```
if(response == 'success')
{
    $("#form1").slideUp('slow', function() {

    });  <--- You Missed ")" here 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

a small mistake

```
$(#"login").click(function() {
```

This should be

```
$("#login").click(function() {
  ^ // # inside quotes.
```

Comment: Ah! Good catch. I made the edit and re-opened the page... the problem is still occurring I'm afraid..

Comment: Gah! there was another syntax error... forgot to close parenths on the .slideUp() function.. after these two fixes, it now works. Thank you very much!

Comment: not the error there tho, OP would have seen that error in firebug's console

Comment: Almost... it is for some reason the message is always 'incorrect username or password'. Even if demo and demo are typed into username and password fields.

Comment: check if the control is entering `if()`